# Checkbox PHP, JS Dentro de un while, con una tabla que se actualiza

Tags: javascript, php

Que tal? estoy intento poner un checkbox a una tabla con datos de una BD que actualiza solo la tabla cada 6seg. El tema es que cuando le doy clic al check, a los 6seg. se borra lo marcado. Hay alguna manera de que quede marcado el checkbox?

vi una respuesta en esta misma web, pero no funciona.

el codigo es:

```
        while ($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($res)) {
    ?>
    <tr>    <td><input class="task-chk" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td><?=$row[0]?></td>
            <td><?=$row[1]?></td>
            <td><?=$row[2]?></td>
            <td><?=str_ireplace($serv_regular, $serv_nueva, $row[3])?></td>
            <td class="datos-td"><?=str_ireplace($desc_regular, $desc_nuevo, $row[4])?></td>
            <td><?=$row[5]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');?></td>
    </tr>
```

el código de JS que probe es este:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".task-chk").forEach((checkbox)  => {
checkbox.checked = window.localStorage.getItem(checkbox.id) == "true" ? true : false;
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function(){
window.localStorage.setItem(checkbox.id, checkbox.checked)});
});
```

Aclaro que soy nuevo con JS, le doy mil vueltas para entenerlo.

y Este es el codigo que me actualiza la tabla:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var pageRefresh = 6000; //6 s
setInterval(function() {
refresh();
}, pageRefresh);
});

function refresh() {
$('#contenido').load(location.href + " #contenido");
$('#Contador').load(location.href + " #Contador");
}
```

agradecere una ayuda!

EDIT:

```
                <tbody style="font-family: monospace;">
            <?php include('query.php'); ?>
            <script>
                
    document.querySelectorAll(".habilitar").forEach((fila) => {
    fila.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    const id = document.querySelector('.id-datos').value
    const formdata = new FormData();
    if (e.target.checked) {
        let habilitar = true
        formdata.append("habilitar", habilitar);
        formdata.append('id', id)
        fetch("archivo.php", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formdata,
        }).then((data) => {
            console.log('Enviado con exito')
        });
    } else {
        let habilitar = false
        formdata.append("habilitar", habilitar);
        formdata.append('id', id)
        fetch("archivo.php", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formdata,
        }).then((data) => {
            console.log('Enviado con exito')
        });
       }
       });
     });</script>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: ¿Para que necesitas recargar la pagina cada 6 segundos?

Comment: en la BD ingresan nuevos datos todos los dias, al refrescar esa tabla, muestro los ultimos 30 cada 6 seg. Creo que hay mejores maneras de hacerlo, pero no se hacerlo aun. Y con el metodo de JS, de actualizar la tabla cada 6 seg., no me funciona lo de mantener el checkbox

Comment: ¿Solo estas mostrando datos o tambien se hace una operacion CRUD?

Comment: solo muestro datos

Comment: Supongo que tienes una columna llamada id en tu tabla de base de datos, ¿cierto?

Comment: Si asi es, es auto incrementable.

Comment: realizare las pruebas, y te comento. gracias !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tienes un id auto incrementable en tu tabla de base de datos, te propongo hacer lo siguiente:

Crear una nueva columna en tu tabla llamada **is_check** que sea de tipo **bool**

Y en tu HTML podrias poner lo siguiente:

```
<td>
    <input type="hidden" class="id-datos" value="<?php echo $row[poner-tu-id-tabla] ?>">
    <?php if ($row[columna-is-check] == true): ?>
    <input type="checkbox" checked class="habilitar task-chk">
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php if ($row[columna-is-check] == false): ?>
    <input type="checkbox" class="habilitar task-chk">
    <?php endif;?>
</td>
```

Despues podrias crear un evento en javascript para que cada vez que se de click al input check, se mande a un archivo externo **(arhivo.php)** si está habilitado o no y mandarlo a actualizar en tu tabla de base datos

```
document.querySelectorAll(".habilitar").forEach((fila) => {
    fila.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
        const id = document.querySelector('.id-datos').value
        const formdata = new FormData();
        if (e.target.checked) {
            let habilitar = true
            formdata.append("habilitar", habilitar);
            formdata.append('id', id)
            fetch("archivo.php", {
                method: "POST",
                body: formdata,
            }).then((data) => {
                console.log('Enviado con exito')
            });
        } else {
            let habilitar = false
            formdata.append("habilitar", habilitar);
            formdata.append('id', id)
            fetch("archivo.php", {
                method: "POST",
                body: formdata,
            }).then((data) => {
                console.log('Enviado con exito')
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Y en **archivo.php** podrias actualizar la tabla de la siguiente manera

```
    $is_check = $_POST['habilitar'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $query = "UPDATE tu_tabla set is_check = '$is_check' WHERE id_tu_tabla = '$id'";
    mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
```

Al recargar tu pagina, se deberia quedar **"marcado"** el check

EDIT:
Intenta probar con el siguiente codigo

```javascript
document.querySelectorAll(".habilitar").forEach((fila) => {
  fila.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    const tr = fila.parentNode.parentNode;
    const id = tr.children[0].children[0].value;
    const formdata = new FormData();
    if (e.target.checked) {
      let habilitar = true;
      formdata.append("id", id);
      formdata.append("habilitar", habilitar);
      console.log(habilitar);
      console.log(`El id es ${id}`);
      fetch("archivo.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formdata,
      })
        .then((data) => {
          console.log("Enviado correctamente");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          throw error;
        });
    } else {
      let habilitar = false;
      formdata.append("id", id);
      formdata.append("habilitar", habilitar);
      console.log(habilitar);
      console.log(`El id es ${id}`);
      fetch("archivo.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formdata,
      })
        .then((data) => {
          console.log("Enviado correctamente");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          throw error;
        });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: funciona perfecto crack, lo unico que me falta, en el archivo.php no me detecta las variables :  Warning: Undefined array key "habilitar" in \archivo.php on line 5
Warning: Undefined array key "id" in \archivo.php on line 6 Lo probe haciendo un update en la bd en la columna, y queda el check. pero desde la web, tengo ese tema.

Comment: No sé como tengas estructurado tu proyecto, lo realicé suponiendo que tienes todos tus archivos en una sola carpeta, estaria bien si me muestras la estructura de tu proyecto

Comment: tengo todo en una sola carpeta ya que es una carpeta de TEST, creo que es tema del script, que no me agarra yo lo puse dentro de la tabla, no se si esta bien ubicado.  Lo edito en mi pregunta de arriba, para que veas la ubicacion

Comment: Deberias poner el script debajo de la tabla y antes de **fetch** podrias poner `console.log(habilitar)` para saber si te está detectando el evento **checked** tanto en **if** como en **else**

Comment: Le agregue el console.log(habilitar) pero no muestra nada :/

Comment: Edité la respuesta con un nuevo codigo, intenta probarlo

Comment: Vale, detecta el checked al hacer el clic en el checkbox, Pero en el archivo.php me sigue diciendo que no esta definida la variables ..

Comment: comprobe, que cuando el estado del input es 1 (haciendo update directo en la BD) aparece el tilde en el checkbox, cuando lo destildo, me hace el update a 0

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141356/discussion-between-matias-tonnera-and-jesus-san1).